# Go, midstate SHA-256 hash

Tags: hash, go, state, sha256, sha

Having 128 bytes of data, for example:

```
00000001c570c4764aadb3f09895619f549000b8b51a789e7f58ea750000709700000000103ca064f8c76c390683f8203043e91466a7fcc40e6ebc428fbcc2d89b574a864db8345b1b00b5ac00000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080020000
```

And wanting to perform SHA-256 hash on it, one would have to separate it into two 64 bytes of data and hash them individually before hashing the results together. If one was to often change some bits in the second half of the data, one could simplify the calculations and hash the first half of the data only once. How would one do that in Google Go? I tried calling

```
func SingleSHA(b []byte)([]byte){
    var h hash.Hash = sha256.New()
    h.Write(b)
    return h.Sum()
}
```

But instead of the proper answer

```
e772fc6964e7b06d8f855a6166353e48b2562de4ad037abc889294cea8ed1070
```

I got

```
12E84A43CBC7689AE9916A30E1AA0F3CA12146CBF886B60103AEC21A5CFAA268
```

When discussing the matter on [Bitcoin forum](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=51281.msg742754#msg742754), someone mentioned that there could be some problems with getting that midstate hash.

How do I calculate a midstate SHA-256 hash in Google Go?

Comment: In Go 1.0.3, Sum takes a byte slice, so you must write `h.Sum([]byte{})` to return

Comment: `h.Sum(nil)` is also valid, @emicklei :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bitcoin-related byte operations are a bit tricky, as they tend to switch endianness at a whim. First of, we take the initial []byte array representing

```
00000001c570c4764aadb3f09895619f549000b8b51a789e7f58ea750000709700000000103ca064f8c76c390683f8203043e91466a7fcc40e6ebc428fbcc2d89b574a864db8345b1b00b5ac00000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080020000
```

Then, we separate out the first half of the array, obtaining:

```
00000001c570c4764aadb3f09895619f549000b8b51a789e7f58ea750000709700000000103ca06 4f8c76c390683f8203043e91466a7fcc40e6ebc428fbcc2d8
```

After that, we need to swap some bytes around. We reverse the order of bytes in every slice of 4 bytes, thusly obtaining:

```
0100000076C470C5F0B3AD4A9F619598B80090549E781AB575EA587F977000000000000064A03C10396CC7F820F8830614E94330C4FCA76642BC6E0ED8C2BC8F
```

And that is the array we will be using for calculating the midstate. Now, we need to alter the file `hash.go`, adding to `type Hash interface`:

```
Midstate() []byte
```

And change the file `sha256.go`, adding this function:

```
func (d *digest) Midstate() []byte {
    var answer []byte
    for i:=0;i<len(d.h);i++{
        answer=append(answer[:], Uint322Hex(d.h[i])...)
    }
    return answer
}
```

Where `Uint322Hex` converts an `uint32` variable into a `[]byte` variable. Having all that, we can call:

```
var h BitSHA.Hash = BitSHA.New()
h.Write(Str2Hex("0100000076C470C5F0B3AD4A9F619598B80090549E781AB575EA587F977000000000000064A03C10396CC7F820F8830614E94330C4FCA76642BC6E0ED8C2BC8F"))
log.Printf("%X", h.Midstate())
```

Where `Str2Hex` turns a `string` into `[]byte`. The result is:

```
69FC72E76DB0E764615A858F483E3566E42D56B2BC7A03ADCE9492887010EDA8
```

Remembering the proper answer:

```
e772fc6964e7b06d8f855a6166353e48b2562de4ad037abc889294cea8ed1070
```

We can compare them:

```
69FC72E7 6DB0E764 615A858F 483E3566 E42D56B2 BC7A03AD CE949288 7010EDA8
e772fc69 64e7b06d 8f855a61 66353e48 b2562de4 ad037abc 889294ce a8ed1070
```

So we can see that we just need to swap the bytes around a bit in each slice of 4 bytes and we will have the proper "midstate" used by Bitcoin pools and miners (until it will no longer be needed due to being deprecated).

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on how you went from `0100000076C470C5F0B3AD4A9F619598B80090549E781AB575EA587F977000000000000064A03C10396CC7F820F8830614E94330C4FCA76642BC6E0ED8C2BC8F` to `69FC72E76DB0E764615A858F483E3566E42D56B2BC7A03ADCE9492887010EDA8` for someone who doesn't know Go? It looks like you're iterating through the hex (converted from string-hex to raw hex), doing something with unsigned ints, and converting back to hex. I'm not sure where the ints are coming from or what you're doing with them... any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: @ConstableJoe I'm sorry, I'm worried some of the magic might be done internally by the SHA algorithm. Moreover, it was a long while since I played with this. Lets see, I put the hex array into the Write function to load it into SHA. The algorithm crunches the numbers in the Write function, and stores them in an array of unsigned ints. I get their values and turn them into an array of hexes. I think that's it.

Comment: @ThePiachu is the reversing the order of bytes every 4 byte a necessary step? It would seem that the result would be byte reversed every 4 bytes then

Answer (score 3):

The Go code you have is the right way to compute sha256 of a stream of bytes.

Most likely the answer is that what you want to do is not sha256. Specifically:

> one would have to separate it into two 64 bits of data and hash them individually before hashing the results together. If one was to often change some bits in the second half of the data, one could simplify the calculations and hash the first half of the data only once.

is not a valid way to calculate sha256 (read http://doc.golang.org/src/pkg/crypto/sha256/sha256.go to e.g. see that sha256 does its work on blocks of data, which must be padded etc.).

The algorithm you described calculates something, but not sha256.

Since you know the expected value you presumably have some reference implementation of your algorithm in another language so just do a line-by-line port to Go.

Finally, it's a dubious optimization in any case. 128 bits is 16 bytes. Hashing cost is usually proportional to the size of data. At 16 bytes, the cost is so small that the additional work of trying to be clever by splitting data in 8 byte parts will likely cost more than what you saved.

Comment: Sorry, I meant bytes, not bits. The implementation that would be using this data is only meant for hashing the data together, altering the second half of the string, so calculating the midstate saves a sizeable part of the computing task.

Comment: I would benchmark the "sizeable part". To me 64 vs 128 bytes is insignificant, especially considering how sha256 works. Sha256 operates on blocks of minimum 56 bytes. Instead of doing sequential sha256 on 128 bytes you want to do it on 64 bytes (padded to 2*56 i.e. 112) for sha256 of half of the data plus again on 32+32 (32 is size of sha256 checksum) plus the overhead of setting up additional sha256 process. In fact, doing it on 128 bytes should be faster (and the results are not equivalent).

Answer (score 2):

In [sha256.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/crypto/sha256/sha256.go), at the start of function `Sum()` the implementation is making a copy of the SHA256 state. The underlying datatype of SHA256 (struct `digest`) is private to the sha256 package.

I would suggest to make your own private copy of the `sha256.go` file (it is a small file). Then add a `Copy()` function to save the current state of the digest:

```
func (d *digest) Copy() hash.Hash {
    d_copy := *d
    return &d_copy
}
```

Then simply call the `Copy()` function to save a midstate SHA256 hash.

Comment: Actually, one also needs to change hash.go file to change the hash.Hash interface to allow one to call Copy(), but even after that I get the result of [BE7E1F35 A19D5938 D8E6A17B 6BDF4738 603BB417 9AE97BCE FAED662 C11CB2F7].

Comment: Okay, lets see... Turns out Bitcoins are a bit tricky with their endianness and a lot of weird byte swapping is going on before the input is fed into the SHA function. In the end, this solution with some alterations would work.